# Abort conversion when one of element fails in to convert in swift

Tags: swift

In swift, we have higher order functions like map, filter, reduce and so on for array

But what if i have an array such as [Any] = [1, 2, 3, "1"].

and i wish to convert this array to an array of Int. But since there is "1" in the array, my logic is to accept this entire array invalid, which i will map to an empty array, let say.

How do i do it with higher functions in this case?

Filtering is easy

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, 3, "1"]
let filtered = array.compactMap{ $0 as? Int}
/// prints [1, 2, 3]
```

but i want the end result to be [], not [1, 2, 3].

How do i achieve that using higher order functions?

Comment: `array as? [Int] ?? []`

Comment: There is no elegant way to do it. One can't use break, continue inside higher order functions.

Comment: @dan Yup, but what is there is some conversion entailed. I know i have given a very trival example. But let  say, they are all [Int], but i want to convert them to an valid array with elements less than, let's say, 100. If any element fails this convertion, i should return an empty array, rather than a filtered one

Comment: @ShreeramBhat You can `throw`.

Comment: @Alexander Throwing and handling using try catch again is this an elegant way for this kind of work?. Better to use for loop.

Comment: @ShreeramBhat It depends on the function you're calling. If it's `map`, then probably a loop looks tidier overall. But generally, `throw` is a generalized "abort this operation" mechanism, that's provided for the language, rather than you needing to build it manually into every high ordered function where you might need it.

Comment: What exact output you want [1, 2, 3] or [1, 2, 3, 1]?

Answer (score 0):

CompactMap

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

So you can't return what you want by using the `compactMap`

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, 3, "1"]


for case let element in array {
    if let _ = element as? Int {
        continue
    } else {
        print("\(element) isn't an Int, so array is invalid")
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `array as? [Int] ?? []` is inapplicable (e.g. you need to apply a more complex transformation), you can `throw` an error instead.

```
enum ConversionError: Error {
    case notAllValuesWereInts
}

func convertOrThrow(_ input: Any) throws -> Int {
    switch input {
        case let int as Int: return int
        default: throw ConversionError.notAllValuesWereInts
    }
}

let array: [Any] = [1, 2, 3, "1"]
let ints: [Int]
do {
    ints = try array.map(convertOrThrow)
} catch {
    ints = []
}
print(ints)
```

In a case like this where the `error` is used for control flow, doesn't carry any useful information, you can use `try?` to simplify things:

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, 3, "1"]
let ints = (try? array.map(convertOrThrow)) ?? []
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this should do the trick as you just want to check whether the array is an array of Integers or not

```
array as? [Int] ?? []
```

But in case you don't want to use above, you might be interested in the following code

```
let filtered = array.filter{($0.self as? Int) == nil}.count == 0 ? array as! [Int] : []
```

The above code yields `[]` if there is any element which is not `Int`